# Render html tag in a label

Tags: html

I want to render a body tag in a label as textual element

```
<label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">
  <strong>Copy and paste this code in Google Tag Manager as custom html or paste this code before </body> tag on your website page(s).</strong>
</label>
```

But how can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Use this `&lt;` for `<` 
,
and `&gt;` for `>`

## Full List

## DEMO

```html
<label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">
  <strong>Copy and paste this code in Google Tag Manager as custom html or paste this code before &lt;/body&gt; tag on your website page(s).</strong>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. You should only have one `<body>` tag, which encompasses all html outside of the `<head>` element and a direct descendant of the `<html>` element